# Reloading dynatree with new data - destroy method or reloadChildren do not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I'm not able to reload dynatree after I received response for AJAX request.
I've a pulldown 'plan.viewType' in code below. I'm invoking a JS function upon a new value selected in this pulldown which will in turn call an AJAX function.

```
<form:select path="plan.viewType" id="viewType" style="width:11.6em" onChange="loadView()" multiple="false">
<form:options items="${plan.viewType}"/>
</form:select>
```

I've two trees - dim_tree and kpi_tree.

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
$.fn.clearable = function (treeid) {
    var $this = this;
    $this.wrap('<div class="clear-holder" />');
    var helper = $('<span class="clear-helper">x</span>');
    $this.parent().append(helper);
    helper.click(function(){
        $this.val("");
        $('#' + treeid).dynatree('getRoot').search("");
    });
};

$("#dimsearch").clearable("dim_tree");
$("#kpisearch").clearable("kpi_tree");

$("#dim_tree").dynatree({
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    children: (isEdit == "true")? eval('('+'${plan_dimension_edit_info}'+')') : eval('('+'${plan_dimension_info}'+')'),
    dnd: {
        onDragStart: function (node) {
            return false;
        },
        onDragStop: function (node) {
            return false;
        },
        onDragOver: function (targetNode, sourceNode, hitMode) {
            return false;
        },
        onDrop: function (targetNode, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(select, node) {
        if(select && dimKPIMisMatch(node)) {
            node.select(false);
            //showToolTip(node.span, dimMsg);
            return;
        }
        createTreeSortable(select, node, "DIM");
    }
});

$("#kpi_tree").dynatree({
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    children: (isEdit == "true")? eval('('+'${plan_measurement_edit_info}'+')') : eval('('+'${plan_measurement_info}'+')'),
    dnd: {
        onDragStart: function (node) {
            return false;
        },
        onDragStop: function (node) {
            return false;
        },
        onDragOver: function (targetNode, sourceNode, hitMode) {
            return false;
        },
        onDrop: function (targetNode, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    onSelect: function(select, node) {
        if(select && kpiDIMMisMatch(node)) {
            node.select(false);
            //showToolTip(node.span, kpiMsg);
            return;
        }
        createTreeSortable(select, node, "KPI");
    }
});
});
```

I would like to reload these two trees when I get response from AJAX call below.

```
var loadView = function() {
if($("#viewType").val() == "Default View") {
    $.ajax({
        url : "planmntsdefault.do",
        type : "GET",
        success : function (data) {
            var node = $("#dim_tree").dynatree("getTree").getRoot();
            if(node && node.isLazy())
            {
                node.reloadChildren(function(node, isOk){
                    if(!isOk) alert("Node " + node + " could not be reloaded.");
                    else alert("Tree reloaded");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                node.activate();
                node.reloadChildren(function(node, isOk){
                    if(!isOk) alert("Node " + node + " could not be reloaded.");
                    else alert("Tree reloaded");
                });
            }

            node = $("#kpi_tree").dynatree("getTree").getRoot();
            if(node && node.isLazy())
            {
                node.reloadChildren(function(node, isOk){
                    if(!isOk) alert("Node " + node + " could not be reloaded.");
                    else alert("Tree reloaded");
                });
            }
            else
            {
                node.activate();
                node.reloadChildren(function(node, isOk){
                    if(!isOk) alert("Node " + node + " could not be reloaded.");
                    else alert("Tree reloaded");
                });
            }
        },
        error : function ( xhr, textStatus, error ) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

I referred to other posts [how to reload/refresh/reinit DynaTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318116/how-to-reload-refresh-reinit-dynatree/7318215#7318215) which didn't resolve the problem. I've tried another variation where I do destroy and reload. Neither of these approaches work. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
    success : function (data) {
        $("#dim_tree").dynatree("getTree").reload();
        $("#kpi_tree").dynatree("getTree").reload();
    },
```

Comment: How is `data` from method is passed to tree?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your problem by three method if you want to add new data and response come by ajax then u can add following code in [dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/)

#### jQuery

```
  $.ajax({
            url : "planmntsdefault.do",
            type : "GET",
            success : function (data) {
                var node = $("#dim_tree").dynatree("getTree").getRoot();
      /*here you can use i assume title 
       come  (by this name of root is set in 
      dynatree and if set isFolder :true then
     folder icon appear in dyna tree*/

             var childNode = node.addChild({  title: data.title,
                             isFolder: true


                                    });        
     }
             })
```

and if u want to edit some root name then you can use

#### In Previous Code Where We Use Add Set Below Line

```
var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
node.data.title = $newtitle;
```

#### And For Delete

```
var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
activeNode.remove();
```

these all steps when we apply then it look that dyna tree referesh hope it make help